# How to define dynamic value on "#define"

Tags: c++

I have some problem with my code.
I wanna using struct array to calculate something.

But my array size is **dynamic** not static.

Here's my code

```
#include <iostream>
#define MAX 5
using namespace std;
struct Point{
    int x,y;
}arrayy[MAX];

int main(){
    int num_howmanytime,num_max;
    cin >> num_howmanytime;
    while(num_howmanytime--){
    cin >> num_max;
    }
}
```

As you can see the **num_max** is dynamic, it will change value according user input what value on it.

So my question is:

How to let **MAX** get the same value with **num_max**

I know that that is not possible so must use others ways, such as

Comment: Use a `std::vector`

Comment: You can allocate the array dynamically at the moment the desired size is known.

Comment: You can't do that. Your code means exactly the same as if you wrote `arrayy[5]`.

Comment: But i wanna wrote like `arrayy[num_max]` , can i do that?

Comment: Then use [`std::vector`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector).

Comment: Obviously you should use a vector not an array. Use the right tools for the job instead of trying to use the tools you know. Much easier in the long run.

Answer (score 3):

> How to let MAX get the same value with num_max?

That's impossible. `MAX` is a compile-time constant (that you would better declare as e.g. `constexpr std::size_t max = 5;` instead of using the preprocessor), while `num_max` is a value determined at runtime.

The difference with respect to array sizes is that you must dynamically allocate the memory for arrays with a runtime-dependent size. As suggested in the comments, you typically don't do that manually, but instead rely on an existing type, often a template.

Example for your case:

```
#include <vector>

std::vector<Point> points;

cin >> num_max;

// Set the runtime array size, let the vector allocate its memory.
// Also, provide a default initial value for all Point instances.
points.resize(num_max, {0, 0});
```

Note that passing the default `Point` instance `{0, 0}` to `std::vector::resize` is optional here, as the function will value-initialize the newly created elements, which is is zero-initialization in this case.

Answer (score 1):

There are some ways here.

- In C++

  You can use `std::vector`

  ```
  struct Point {
      int x, y;
  };

  int main() {
      int num_howmanytime, num_max;
      cin >> num_howmanytime;
      while (num_howmanytime--) {
          cin >> num_max;
          std::vector<Point> arrayy(num_max);
      }
      return 0;
  }
  ```
- In C(since C99)

  You can use VLA(Variable-length array)

  ```
  struct Point {
      int x, y;
  };

  int main() {
      int num_howmanytime, num_max;
      scanf("%d", &num_howmanytime);
      while (num_howmanytime--) {
          scanf("%d", &num_max);
          struct Point arrayy[num_max];
      }
      return 0;
  }
  ```
- In C(before C99)

  You can allocate the memory dynamically

  ```
  struct Point {
      int x, y;
  };

  int main() {
      int num_howmanytime, num_max;
      scanf("%d", &num_howmanytime);
      while (num_howmanytime--) {
          scanf("%d", &num_max);
          struct Point *arrayy;
          arrayy = malloc(sizeof(struct Point) * num_max);
      }
      return 0;
  }
  ```

Comment: The question is tagged C++ and uses `<iostream>`. Why bring up C?

Comment: @MSalters It tagged `C` and `C++` yesterday. Someone removed the `C` tag